# Backbone and Laravel API

Tags: php, api, backbone.js, curl, laravel

A couple of questions that I cannot seem to find definative answers for, I am working on a RESTful api at the moment, that in time will interact with a handful of client devices, for the time being I am concetrating, on the API, and the web application that goes along with it.

The api lives at http://api.local and the web application lives at http://webapplication.local.  The web application is a Laravel installation with a Backbone front-end.

I am trying to save some data from the Backbone to the database of the API. So the API save method looks like this,

```
public function store()
{
    $user_details = Input::all();

    $user = new User;

    $user->firstname = $user_details['firstname'];
    $user->surname = $user_details['surname'];
    $user->email = $user_details['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($user_details['password']);
    $user->remember_token = '';

    $user->save();

    return Response::json($user_details, 200);
}
```

And it has a route that looks like this,

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){

   Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index');
   Route::get('users/{id}', 'UsersController@get');
   Route::post('users/create', 'UsersController@store');
   /**
   * PUT request to edit the database record
   * @todo: Need to be a PUT request in the long run
   */
   Route::post('users/update/{id}', 'UsersController@update');
   /**
   * DELETE request to edit the database record
   * @todo: Need to be a DELETE request in the long run
   */
   Route::post('users/delete/{id}', 'UsersController@delete');

});
```

On the front end side (web application) I am saving a model like this,

```
saveNewUser: function(e) {

    e.preventDefault()
    var data = this.$el.find('.js-create-new-user').serializeJSON();

    // create a new model
    var User = new app.User();

    User.save(data, {
        success: function(model, response){
            console.log(model);
            console.log(response);
            console.log("sucess");
        },
        error: function(model, response) {
            console.log(model);
        },
        wait:true
    });

}
```

This sends a POST request to the webapplication.local/users/create method, that looks like this,

```
public function create()
    {
        $data = Input::all();

        $curl = new Curl\Curl();

        $curl->post('http://pops.local/api/v1/users/create', $data);

        if ($curl->error) {
            return Response::json($curl->error, $curl->error_code);
        }
        else {
          return Response::json($curl->response, 200);
        }
    }
```

If I look at the `$curl->response` then I see the data object that is being sent - which I assume means the cURL request is successfully being sent. However nothing gets updated in the API's database?

Am I going about this all wrong? Should Backbone be sending/making requests directly to the API, and leave the PHP behind the web application to do things that the API does not do i.e resize images etc?

Comment: You may send requests directly from backbone but you dont have to. Everything looks fine. Please check what is returned from `$user->save();` ( `dd($user->save());` )

Comment: @Kasyx is you create this an answer I will tick it off, this helped get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may send requests directly from backbone but you dont have to. Everything looks fine. Check what is returned from `$user->save();` by writing something like that:

```
dd($user->save());
```

You should get `true` if everyting is fine, `false` if there is any error.